# Adding/assigning numbers to duplicate rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have one table of names and addresses, and two queries:

```
$authors = "SELECT * FROM authors";

$addresses = "SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS addno, a.authorAdd FROM (SELECT DISTINCT authorAdd FROM authors) a JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r";
```

The second currently assigns unique row numbers to each unique address like so:

```
66 Acacia Avenue   1
301 Penny Lane    2
```

What I need to do is somehow combine these two queries in PHP to produce a list of authors with addresses with these assigned numbers. i.e.

```
Name        Address           AddressNo
Joe Blogs   66 Acacia Avenue  1
Bob Smith   301 Penny Lane    2
Jane Blogs  66 Acacia Avenue  1
Sarah Smith 301 Penny Lane    2
```

So that I can display them as references:

Joe Blogs(1), Bob Smith(2), Jane Blogs(1), Sarah Smith(2)

(1) 66 Acacia Avenue, (2) 301 Penny Lane

I've thought about adding jquery to add the numbers dynamically for insertion directly into the database on submission, but not sure how that would work.

So have opted for the PHP display option, which is proving tricky, as if I combined the two queries into one query it was essentially reassign row numbers on all results, and I only need them for the one query (the addresses), if that makes sense.

Any help would be gratefully received! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get by `mysql` using `session variable`

```
set @addressCount = 1;
set @old_address = null;
SELECT `name`, address, AddressNo FROM (
    SELECT `name`, address,@old_address,    
    if(@old_address is null , @addressCount := 1,''),    
    IF(address <> @old_address, @addressCount := (@addressCount +1) , '' ) ,
    @addressCount AS AddressNo,
    @old_address := address
    FROM authors 
    ORDER BY address
) AS TEMP;
```

You can see example here [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ca49/1). I am not php developer and you can use mysql so inside php code you can run this query. this will help you.

Comment: Thanks however, I need to assign the same number to the duplicates rather than the count number. So both instances of 66 Acacia Avenue are number 1 and both instances of 301 Penny Lane are number 2, sadly not as easy as adding a count ref.

Comment: you want  '66 Acacia Avenue' is assign 1 then how many time it will come , in all occurrence of '66 Acacia Avenue' will assing 1. am i right ?

Comment: That right, and the same for all the other addresses

Comment: @SarahCW please check updated query and also sqlfiddle

Comment: Awesome, it worked, your my hero! I thought this would be impossible. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my resut:

**CREATE PROC**

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION rownr (s CHAR(64))
    RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
  BEGIN
    IF s = @rownr_oldval THEN
      SET @rownr_nr:=@rownr_nr+1;
    ELSE
      SET @rownr_nr:=1;
    END IF;

    SET @rownr_oldval:=s;
    RETURN @rownr_nr;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

**Get result**

```
SELECT  rownr(Address),m.* FROM authors m,(SELECT rownr('')) AS tmp ORDER by Address;
```

If you want a other sort in the result you must put a SELECT around.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (
   SELECT  rownr(Address),m.* FROM authors m,(SELECT rownr('')) AS tmp
   ORDER by  Address
  ) ORDER by YOURFIELD;
```

Please let me know if that works for you

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to do it without using stored procedures (not that familiar with this)?